# Is there a way to force 'git pull' to overwrite files instead unlink + create

Tags: git

On the server I have a project in a directory with immutable flag on.
I can update my project files with `git pull` only if there is no file changed in project root.

- project_root  (755 +i)

  - .git        (755)
  - subfolder   (755)

    - file      (644)
  - .gitignore  (644)

If I have changes only in `/project_root/subfolder/file`, I can update it with git pull.

But if I have changes in `/project_root/.gitignore`, git pull fails with `error: unable to unlink old '.gitignore': Operation not permitted`.

The +i flag on `project_root` prevents git (any anybody else) to unlink (and create) .gitignore.

But the file can be modified.

My current workaround after a failed pull is: overwite the file with FTP and run `git checkout -f ...`

Is there a way to force `git pull` to actualy overwrite the file and not unlink old + create new? (The user executing `git pull` has no root permissions, so (temporary) removing the immutable flag from project_root is not a way to go.)

Comment: Rather than using ftp, you should be able to git fetch and then use `git show` to overwrite the file.  Doesn't solve the problem, but seem an easier work flow than falling back on ftp

Comment: No. Or rather, not without obtaining the Git source code, changing the existing code—this is nontrivial; there are good reasons for Git to use `unlink` here—and building a new binary.

Comment: IMHO, git is not a deployment tool, and `git pull` is certainly not a magical "it will work in all conditions" deploy command. I strongly suggest you write a deployment script.